# httpd/apachectl service fails to start on RHEL 7

Tags: linux, apache, redhat, httpd.conf, rhel7

I'm having some trouble launching my Apache server from RHEL 7 (Amazon ec2). My larger goal is to host a Flask application from the ec2 instance using an Anaconda environment, but right now I'm just concerned with getting the httpd service started properly.

I've found a number of similar questions posted [here](https://centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=62767), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44280173/job-for-httpd-service-failed-because-the-control-process-exited-with-error-code), [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/686825/job-for-httpd-service-failed?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), etc., but none seem to address the exact problem I'm experiencing.

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.apptic.me/blog/setting-up-flask-with-red-hat-on-aws.php) down to the last `>` character, but the commands

`sudo apachectl restart`

and

`sudo service httpd restart`

both result in errors and direct me to examine `systemctl status httpd.service` for more information. The output of that file is as follows:

```
httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2018-04-06 21:00:42 UTC; 4s ago
Docs: man:httpd(8)
      man:apachectl(8)
Process: 32166 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Process: 32165 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 32165 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
[long ec2 ip address] systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
[long ec2 ip address] httpd[32165]: httpd (pid 28220) already running
[long ec2 ip address] kill[32166]: kill: cannot find process ""
[long ec2 ip address] systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
[long ec2 ip address] systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
[long ec2 ip address] systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
[long ec2 ip address] systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
```

The output of `journalctl -xe` returns the same.

Some information about my system (don't know whether or not any of this will be helpful, but I figured it would be best to include it):

```
Apache Version: Apache/2.4.6 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux) configured

$ /usr/bin/python -V
    Python 2.7.5
$ sudo yum install mod_wsgi
    Package mod_wsgi-3.4-12.el7_0.x86_64 already installed and latest version
$ service httpd configtest
    Syntax OK
$ sudo chkconfig --levels 235 httpd on
    Note: Forwarding request to 'systemctl enable httpd.service'
```

The command `sudo netstat -lnp | grep :80` returns `tcp 0 0 :::0 :::* LISTEN 28220/httpd`

I am now noticing that the file `/etc/init.d/httpd` does not exist.

Anybody have a hint? If this question has been asked before, please direct me to it. I've searched all over, with no luck thus far.

Cheers.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww Thanks for the tip, I'll try those

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try killing the old `pid`. Looks like something is still running under `httpd`. Try doing a `ps -ef | grep httpd` to see what is running and kill it using `sudo kill -9 processid` (e.g. `sudo kill -9 13254`).

Comment: This was it, thank you. Answer given in this thread: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/436238/apache-httpd-server-fails-to-start-on-redhat-7-amazon-ec2-instance/436273#436273

Comment: yes it worked for me why this error arises i went through the documentation but not got any justified answer